# Code Signing Profiles: What do I need to select? And what scheme do I need to run for the release?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I'll soon upload my first app to the Apple store but I'm still confused what I need to select in the code signing options in my project (or target?). So far I've distributed my beta version to beta testers with my Adhoc provisioning profile and it did work. However now I'm confused what do I need to do for the final release?

1. Does the "Release xx" need to be the same as the "Any iOS SDK?" or does the Release need to be "Don't Code sign"? And do they need to be the same in the target as in the project? (I only have one target..my app).
2. The provisioning profile at the bottom of the screen: Do I need my Adhoc profile (for the debuggers) only in the debug version or in both? What do I need for the final release version?
3. What scheme do I need to run for the release to the app store?! Do I need to select "Release" for the archive or doesn't it matter?

Sorry this is my first app and I'm still very confused regarding all these options...and I've read through the Apple manual but still don't really get it. And after several tries I've finally managed to get the beta version running but I don't know if I did everything really the way it should be.

**My project settings:**
[image]

**My target settings:**
[image: My target settings]

Answer (score 1):

This can definitely become a headache very quickly. It sounds like you're just missing the app store provision.

For your final release you'll create a new distribution profile just like you created your ad hoc provision, but instead of creating an ad hoc provision you will create an 'app store' provision (it's one of the options provided when you click + on the distribution profile screen in iTunes Connect). Open up xcode > preferences and refresh your provisions so you have them local & then update the settings here.

When you're ready to submit:

- Go to the iTunes connect area, add your app, click 'ready to submit'
- Archive
- Click Distribute in the organizer
- Select 'Submit to the iOS App Store'
- Select your app store distribution provision
- Submit

Comment: Thx alot David. This helps quite a bit. And how about the code signing stuff, do I need to change there something or does this XCode automatically?

Comment: You may want to flip that release identity to your distribution identity, but changing the provision profile (below that area) should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 5, it doesn't matter. Just sign using any provisioning profile. You will be able to re-resign your app when you export it using **XCode Organizer > Distribute...**.

You just need to make sure that the development provisioning profile used and the distribution profile have matching app IDs.

This is very confusing in general. The best thing to do is to read, re-read and read again the [guide from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH1-SW1) and make sure you understand the purpose of everything. Trust me, even long term developers are still confused about this process.